# How to unit test a function that randomizes an option selection?

Tags: unit-testing, go

```golang
func RandomAgentType() AgentType {
    types := []AgentType{
        AgentTypeArtist,
        AgentTypeCollector,
        AgentTypePrivateInstitution,
        AgentTypePublicInstitution,
    }

    return types[rand.Intn(len(types))]
}
```

Is there even a point in unit testing such a function at all? If so, how does one go about it? It relies pretty much on `rand.Intn` working and that is already taken care of by the core `go` library.

Would it affect the coverage percentage if not given any test?

Comment: WHAT do you want to test is the question. If you add a new "AgentType" later is it important that that list gets updated?

Comment: you could check that every element in the array is returned with a probability of 1 / size(array).

Comment: @DrGo except that you can't because that's not how randomness works. Getting heads 10 times in a row in a coin toss doesn't mean the result isn't random.

Comment: Like DrGo said, test for the ideal distribution over a loop of 100,000 iterations. The testify library has a Delta test that allows you to test for something like 50% for example, within a specified range of 4 points plus or minus. You could run this without testify of course. Also setting the same random seed for a test is good to get consistent test results.

Comment: @Adrian sure you can. What I said is literally the definition of classical probability

Comment: @DrGo "every element in the array is returned with a probability of 1 / size(array)" would be true for round-robin, which is not random, and likely would not be true - certainly not *reliably* true - for true randomness.

Comment: @Adrian so if I run a program that has a good pseudorandom generator millions of times and calculates the proportion of trials each element was returned and found it to be 1/size(array), you won't consider that a validation that the function is doing its jobs? why?

Comment: @DrGo the opposite. If it found it to be different, I wouldn't consider it proof it wasn't doing its job. Also running it millions of times would take a lot of time and make it useless as a unit test, and would make it more a test of the `random` package than the actual unit under test. The correct way to test randomness is an actual statistical analysis of the distribution of results, but the randomness of the stdlib isn't in question here, so it shouldn't be tested at all.

Comment: @Adrian What would "an actual statistical analysis of the distribution of results" involve? My suggestion tests both the stdlib pseudorandom generator (even if it was not needed) and the function (e.g., if an entry is duplicated or omitted by mistake). In modern system, running this test million times or so won't take "a lot of time".

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no point in testing such functions (because you are going to tests `stdlib` behaviour). But if you want you can use the `linkname` ([Compiler Directives](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/compile#hdr-Compiler_Directives)) directive to override behavior of `stdlib` (or other) functions:

```
//go:linkname intn math/rand.Intn
func intn(n int) int {
    if n <= 0 {
        return 0
    }
    return n - 1
}

func Test(t *testing.T) {
    for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
        rtype := RandomAgentType()
        if AgentTypePublicInstitution != rtype {
            t.Fail()
        }
    }
}
```

<kbd>[PLAYGROUND](https://go.dev/play/p/fhb1VTOBYvO)</kbd>